# Can you suppress/stop alerts based on the alert content?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I'm really scratching my head because I can't find a way to mute/suppress alerts that match the alert message. I could not do it through events, or with "is_exact_match" option in the alert configuration. For example if the alert says "can't find job 123 in {{host.name}}" then just mute that alert that matches "job 123". The current muting mechanism is so general that it would mute ALL alerts from whatever host or url this is coming from. Any input is appreciated.

- event creation based on monitor
- use syntax to match string in alarm configuration